# Test if user has entered a word equal to a word in a text file

Tags: python, file

Let's say that I have a file with this in it:

```
passcode
```

Now, what I want to do is have some code with user input that should test if what the user entered what is equal to what is in the file. Is there a any way I can do this? Here is the code that I already have:

```
with file('test.txt') as f:
    s.strip('\n')
    s = f.read()

inp = raw_input()
if inp == s:
    print "Access granted"
else: 
    print "Access denied!"
```

Comment: Do you have any code to begin with?

Comment: @Rod_Xavier I can add some.

Comment: Kindly post what you have in here.

Comment: If you are doing this for password checking, this is _not_ the right way.

Comment: @mshsayem what should I do then, can you give an example?

Comment: @Rod_Xavier added some code, as per your request.

Comment: long topic. tldr: you should store a _hash_ of the password (_not_ the exact password).  btw, do `s.strip('\n')` before checking...

Comment: Indeed. If this is just a toy example, that's one thing. If it's actually meant for production checking of a password for a file, this is NOT at all how to do it. Don't roll your own file protection schemes, there are many already out there (including ones built into the OS)

Comment: I agree with @mshsayem. You should not store passwords in plain text.

Comment: ahhh. do `s.strip()` _after_ reading the file contents.

Comment: @mshsayem, how could I store it as a hash and then check it? (Sorry if this bothers you, I am still fairly new to programming. Just look at my username.)

Comment: Don't worry about the hash thing, Code Guy.  If you were writing a real system, it would be important.  For what you are doing, you are almost there.

Comment: If you're doing this for practice, you almost have what you want. Just switch the lines `s.strip('\n')` and `s=f.read()`. :)

Comment: use any hash scheme (say `sha256`) from the `hashlib` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your code and added the following line at the end:

```
print repr(inp), repr(s)
```

The output I got was

```
'passcode' 'passcode\n'
```

Apparently `raw_input()` included the newline at the end.  Strip that off and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

A quick edit you could also do is save `s` in another Python file and call it in your code using `import` as below. The Python file with the data for `s` is called "data.py" in the same directory.

But I do agree with others about using a hash scheme if you're checking passwords.

```
import data

inp = raw_input()

if inp == data.s:
    print "Access granted"
else: 
    print "Access denied!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a simple password username.

```
 import time
 import sys
 username = raw_input('ENTER USERNAME: ')
 password = raw_input('ENTER PASSWORD: ')
 if username == '(enter any name here)':
     if password == '(enter any password here)':
         print 'ACCESS GRANTED'
else:
    print 'ACCESS DENIED'
    time.sleep(.05)
    sys.exit()
```